# Detect headphones in JavaScript/MobileSafari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

Is it possible in JavaScript on MobileSafari to detect whether audio is being played through headphones as opposed to the inbuilt speaker?

Answer (score 3):

no it is not. If you want that level of interaction with the underlying operating system, you need an app. Maybe you could look into making an app with phonegap or the like, which basically creates a webview to contain your app (in the form of a web page), but exposes parts of the underlying operating system to the webview.